# Conclusions from the delayed choice eraser double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, quantum-eraser

Is it safe to say the point of all of these one particle slit experiments is that the very existence of "which way" information is what collapses the wave function even in the case that information will have been "encoded" in the quantum system after the particle already passed through?